# bootstrap carousel slider slide not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

i am using bootstrap in my site and also use carousel slider and it's working fine but problem is when slider slide image right to left it will take second image when first image reach completely to left so,1ms or 2ms second it will display white space between slide. so,i don't want that white space and i want that when slider slide from right to left second image must immediately appear after first one. sorry for my bad english and my slider looks like
[image]

you can see white space there so i want is my next image should appear after previous image and i gess problem in carousel.js and it is.

```
/* ========================================================================
* Bootstrap: carousel.js v3.0.0
* http://twbs.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel
* ========================================================================
* Copyright 2012 Twitter, Inc.
*
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
* You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
* http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
* ========================================================================     */


+function ($) { "use strict";

// CAROUSEL CLASS DEFINITION
// =========================

var Carousel = function (element, options) {
this.$element    = $(element)
this.$indicators = this.$element.find('.carousel-indicators')
this.options     = options
this.paused      =
this.sliding     =
this.interval    = 
this.$active     =
this.$items      = null

this.options.pause == 'hover' && this.$element
  .on('mouseenter', $.proxy(this.pause, this))
  .on('mouseleave', $.proxy(this.cycle, this))
}

Carousel.DEFAULTS = {
interval: 5000
, pause: 'hover'
, wrap: true
}

Carousel.prototype.cycle =  function (e) {
e || (this.paused = false)

this.interval && clearInterval(this.interval)

this.options.interval
  && !this.paused
  && (this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.next, this),     this.options.interval))

return this
}

Carousel.prototype.getActiveIndex = function () {
this.$active = this.$element.find('.item.active')
this.$items  = this.$active.parent().children()

return this.$items.index(this.$active)
}

Carousel.prototype.to = function (pos) {
var that        = this
var activeIndex = this.getActiveIndex()

if (pos > (this.$items.length - 1) || pos < 0) return

if (this.sliding)       return this.$element.one('slid', function () { that.to(pos) })
if (activeIndex == pos) return this.pause().cycle()

return this.slide(pos > activeIndex ? 'next' : 'prev', $(this.$items[pos]))
}

Carousel.prototype.pause = function (e) {
e || (this.paused = true)

if (this.$element.find('.next, .prev').length && $.support.transition.end) {
  this.$element.trigger($.support.transition.end)
  this.cycle(true)
}

this.interval = clearInterval(this.interval)

return this
}

Carousel.prototype.next = function () {
if (this.sliding) return
return this.slide('next')
}

Carousel.prototype.prev = function () {
if (this.sliding) return
return this.slide('prev')
}

Carousel.prototype.slide = function (type, next) {
var $active   = this.$element.find('.item.active')
var $next     = next || $active[type]()
var isCycling = this.interval
var direction = type == 'next' ? 'left' : 'right'
var fallback  = type == 'next' ? 'first' : 'last'
var that      = this

if (!$next.length) {
  if (!this.options.wrap) return
  $next = this.$element.find('.item')[fallback]()
}

this.sliding = true

isCycling && this.pause()

var e = $.Event('slide.bs.carousel', { relatedTarget: $next[0], direction: direction })

if ($next.hasClass('active')) return

if (this.$indicators.length) {
  this.$indicators.find('.active').removeClass('active')
  this.$element.one('slid', function () {
    var $nextIndicator = $(that.$indicators.children()[that.getActiveIndex()])
    $nextIndicator && $nextIndicator.addClass('active')
  })
}

if ($.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('slide')) {
  this.$element.trigger(e)
  if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return
  $next.addClass(type)
  $next[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
  $active.addClass(direction)
  $next.addClass(direction)
  $active
    .one($.support.transition.end, function () {
      $next.removeClass([type, direction].join(' ')).addClass('active')
      $active.removeClass(['active', direction].join(' '))
      that.sliding = false
      setTimeout(function () { that.$element.trigger('slid') }, 0)
    })
    .emulateTransitionEnd(600)
} else if(this.$element.hasClass('slide')) {
    this.$element.trigger(e)
    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return
    $active.animate({left: (direction == 'right' ? '100%' : '-100%')}, 600, function(){
        $active.removeClass('active')
        that.sliding = false
        setTimeout(function () { that.$element.trigger('slid') }, 0)
    })
    $next.addClass(type).css({left: (direction == 'right' ? '-100%' : '100%')}).animate({left: 0}, 600,  function(){
        $next.removeClass(type).addClass('active')
    })
} else {
  this.$element.trigger(e)
  if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return
  $active.removeClass('active')
  $next.addClass('active')
  this.sliding = false
  this.$element.trigger('slid')
}

isCycling && this.cycle()

return this
}


// CAROUSEL PLUGIN DEFINITION
// ==========================

var old = $.fn.carousel

$.fn.carousel = function (option) {
return this.each(function () {
  var $this   = $(this)
  var data    = $this.data('bs.carousel')
  var options = $.extend({}, Carousel.DEFAULTS, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option)
  var action  = typeof option == 'string' ? option : options.slide

  if (!data) $this.data('bs.carousel', (data = new Carousel(this, options)))
  if (typeof option == 'number') data.to(option)
  else if (action) data[action]()
  else if (options.interval) data.pause().cycle()
})
}

$.fn.carousel.Constructor = Carousel


// CAROUSEL NO CONFLICT
// ====================

$.fn.carousel.noConflict = function () {
$.fn.carousel = old
return this
}


// CAROUSEL DATA-API
// =================

$(document).on('click.bs.carousel.data-api', '[data-slide], [data-slide-to]', function (e) {
var $this   = $(this), href
var $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '')) //strip for ie7
var options = $.extend({}, $target.data(), $this.data())
var slideIndex = $this.attr('data-slide-to')
if (slideIndex) options.interval = false

$target.carousel(options)

if (slideIndex = $this.attr('data-slide-to')) {
  $target.data('bs.carousel').to(slideIndex)
}

e.preventDefault()
})

$(window).on('load', function () {
$('[data-ride="carousel"]').each(function () {
  var $carousel = $(this)
  $carousel.carousel($carousel.data())
})
})

}(window.jQuery);
```

and i am using bootstrap.css

```
.carousel {
position: relative;
}
.carousel-inner {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-inner > .item {
position: relative;
display: none;
-webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
   -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
      transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
line-height: 1;
}
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
.carousel-inner > .item {
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition:      -o-transform .6s ease-in-out;
        transition:         transform .6s ease-in-out;

-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
        perspective: 1000;
}
.carousel-inner > .item.next,
.carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
left: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-inner > .item.prev,
.carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
left: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
.carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
.carousel-inner > .item.active {
left: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
.carousel-inner > .active,
.carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-inner > .prev {
display: block;
}
.carousel-inner > .active {
left: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-inner > .prev {
 position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .next {
left: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .prev {
left: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .next.left,
.carousel-inner > .prev.right {
left: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.left {
left: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.right {
left: 100%;
}
.carousel-control {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 15%;
font-size: 20px;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
opacity: .5;
}
.carousel-control.left {
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 100%);
 background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 100%);
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001)));
 background-image:         linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#80000000', endColorstr='#00000000', GradientType=1);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.carousel-control.right {
 right: 0;
 left: auto;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
 background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)));
 background-image:         linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000', GradientType=1);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.carousel-control:hover,
.carousel-control:focus {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
filter: alpha(opacity=90);
outline: 0;
opacity: .9;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
z-index: 5;
display: inline-block;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left {
left: 50%;
margin-left: -10px;
}
.carousel-control .icon-next,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
right: 50%;
margin-right: -10px;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
margin-top: -10px;
font-family: serif;
line-height: 1;
}
.carousel {
.item {
left: 0 !important;
.transition(opacity .4s); //adjust timing here
}
.carousel-control {
background-image: none; // remove background gradients on controls
}
// Fade controls with items
.next.left,
.prev.right {
opacity: 1;
z-index: 1;
}
.active.left,
.active.right {
opacity: 0;
z-index: 2;
}
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev:before {
content: '\2039';
}
.carousel-control .icon-next:before {
content: '\203a';
}
.carousel-indicators {
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
left: 50%;
z-index: 15;
width: 60%;
padding-left: 0;
margin-left: -30%;
text-align: center;
list-style: none;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 margin: 1px;
 text-indent: -999px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #000 \9;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 10px;
 }
.carousel-indicators .active {
width: 12px;
height: 12px;
margin: 0;
background-color: #fff;
}
.carousel-caption {
position: absolute;
right: 15%;
bottom: 20px;
left: 15%;
z-index: 10;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
.carousel-caption .btn {
text-shadow: none;
}
```

and my html is.

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="images/slide/im1.jpg" alt="im1" style="width:100%;">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/slide/im2.jpg" alt="im2" style="width:100%;">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/slide/im3.jpg" alt="im3" style="width:100%;">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/slide/im4.jpg" alt="im4" style="width:100%;">
  </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share you HTML/CSS code ! because, its not gonna help us neither you.

Comment: @Deepak Yadav i change my code and add HTML/CSS. please help me.

Comment: if possible reproduce the issue in fiddle

Comment: your code is working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cfuffcqL/1/) (Just updated the `src` of images) . what are you expecting ? i mean you want more than one image in each slide or to fill up the entire space with one image ?

Comment: after image goes right to left next image won't appear direct or immediate see in image of question but i change my code like answer below it's working like i want but i don't get how's it happen please help me to understand that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below working html code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div data-example-id="simple-carousel" class="bs-example">
  <div data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide" id="carousel-example-generic">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#carousel-example-generic"></li>
      <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#carousel-example-generic"></li>
      <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#carousel-example-generic"></li>
    </ol>
    <div role="listbox" class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img alt="First slide [900x500]" data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#777:#555/text:First slide" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
        data-holder-rendered="true">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img alt="Second slide [900x500]" data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#666:#444/text:Second slide" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
        data-holder-rendered="true">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img alt="Third slide [900x500]" data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#555:#333/text:Third slide" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
        data-holder-rendered="true">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a data-slide="prev" role="button" href="#carousel-example-generic" class="left carousel-control">
      <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a data-slide="next" role="button" href="#carousel-example-generic" class="right carousel-control">
      <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you forgot to include jquery.

Comment: your code is working and is exactly what i am looking for but i don't understand how you done that i want to know?

Comment: Dear i make one carousal example for you and share. :)

Comment: Why you put bootsrap.min.js at bottom of the page, instead of next to jquery.js. ?  any comments on that.
because when I am adding in my sample  very next to jquery.js and run it's not functioning. I am curious on that.  i used jquery - 2.2.3v and bootstrap - 3.3.6v